# how can i get dynamic value input and store it into the state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am using react js. I am trying to get the dynamic input values from a modal, the problem is I am not able to get the input values in a proper way. I am trying to get when the user selects the `size` the state will save only one value small or extra-large also user can select multiple values in `extra ingredirents` which will store in the state.

[image]

The above image is my UI, as you can see I can select multiple values in the radio button which I don't want. I know where the problem is but didn't get any solution. I have commented on my jsx code where the problem is.

Here is the radio button and checkbox jsx code. **the input values are dynamic I have hardcoded the values**

```
// Radio buttons
{products.options.map((product, i) => {
                return (
                  <li onChange={(e) => getItemValues(e.target, product)}>
                    <label className="container_radio">
                      Medium size
                      <span>+ $5.00</span>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        value={5.00}
                        name={options.title} // Here i have added dynamic value that is why the radio button is selecting multiple 
                      />
                      <span className="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>
<li onChange={(e) => getItemValues(e.target, product)}>
                    <label className="container_radio">
                      Extra Largse size
                      <span>+ $8.00</span>
                      <input
                        type="radio"
                        value={8.00}
                        name={'Extra Largse size'} // If I wrote like this the radio button are selecting only one
                      />
                      <span className="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                  </li>
                );
              })}

// checkboxes, checkboxes will be more I just hardcoded only one
 {product.ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
                    return (
                      <li onChange={(e) => getItemValues(e.target, product)}>
                        <label className="container_check">
                          Extra Tomato
                          <span>+ $2</span>
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            value={2}
                            name={'Extra-Tomato'}
                          />
                          <span className="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
```

Here is the function where I am trying to store the data

```
 const [itemDetail, setItemDetail] = useState([]);
  const getItemValues = (e, product) => {
    setItemDetail((prevValue) => {
      const existingProduct = prevValue.find(
        (item) => item.title === product.title
      );
      if (existingProduct) {
        existingProduct.options = {
          ...existingProduct.options,
          [e.name]: e.value,
        };
        return prevValue;
      } else {
        /* new entry */
        return [
          ...prevValue,
          { title: product.title, options: { [e.name]: e.value } },
        ];
      }
    });
  };
```

If I select `extra large` and `ketchup` the output looks like the below code: as you can see I am getting only one value which is `ketchup`, I should get also the `extra large` value maybe there is a problem with my function.

```
[{options: {ketchup: '1'}
title: "ketchup}]
```

My expected output is:

```
[{title: 'Barnes Chapman', options:{extra large: '8.0', ketchup: '1.00' } }]
```

Also, i want if unselect the `ketchup` the ketchup value will be removed from the state also for the radio buttons.

Comment: you should set the same name in radio buttons which should be grouped.

Comment: The radio buttons name will be different.

Comment: That's the reason! `name` should be set to a same name in group.

Comment: Please set `name` to the same name (e.g. `size-raido`) in 3 size radioboxes

Comment: ok, I understood the problem, the other problem is I can change the state only twice, when I click 3rd time on my radio button or checkbox the state is not updating the new value